# GridView with dynamic number of TextViews

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-gridview

I am trying to create a `GridView` with a dynamic number of `TextView`s for each item.

Here is a mockup of what I going for:

```
|-----------------|
|  Text  |  Text  |
|        |  Text  |
|-----------------|
|  Text  |  Text  |
|  Text  |        |
|  Text  |        |
|-----------------|
|  Text  |  Text  |
|  Text  |  Text  |
|-----------------|
```

Notice that each `GridView` item has a dynamic number if `TextView`s, depending on the data returned from my API.

My question is, how do I modify my code below to inflate a `TextView` for each text I want to add in the `GridView` item?

Here is the code I use to call the adapter (removed irrelevant code):

```
private GridView gridView;

// Create a map to hold the text for each GridView item
// The Integer is simply the section number
private List<Map<Integer, List<String>>> items = new ArrayList<>();

// Get the GridView view
gridView = findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

// Add sample items to the list
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, Collections.singletonList("Item 1"));

Map<Integer, List<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put(2, Arrays.asList("Item 1", "Item 2"));

Map<Integer, List<String>> map3 = new HashMap<>();
map3.put(3, Arrays.asList("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"));

Map<Integer, List<String>> map4 = new HashMap<>();
map4.put(4, Collections.singletonList("Item 1"));

// Add the items to the list
items.add(map);
items.add(map2);
items.add(map3);
items.add(map4);

// Initialize the adapter
GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getContext(), items);
gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
```

Here is my `GridView` adapter:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Context mContext;
    private final List<Map<Integer, List<String>>> items;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, List<Map<Integer, List<String>>> items) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.items = items;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        Map<Integer, List<String>> item = items.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : item.entrySet()) {
            Integer key = entry.getKey();
            List<String> values = entry.getValue();

            // For each value, inflate a TextView layout...
            for (String value : values) {
                // What goes here?
                // How do I inflate the TextView layout (shown below) for each value and add it to the parent view?
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        // What goes here?
    }

}
```

Here is my `gridview_item` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

And lastly, here is my `gridview_textview` layout that I want to inflate and add to the above layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

How would I achieve this and what would the code look like?

Comment: I noticed this is your first question - just wanted to say this is very well thought out and presented. Thanks for taking the time to walk through your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager` instead of a `GridView`.

In either case, you want your ViewHolder to do the following (hard for me to mock up the code, so I'm just going to write the steps:

- Your ViewHolder would inflate a `gridview_item` layout and get a reference to the LinearLayout.
- You would have a method on your viewholder like `bindStrings(List<String> strings)` which would inflate a textview for each one.

Here's what the code would look like:

```
public void bindStrings(List<String> strings) {
   Context context = myItemView.getContext();
   LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) myItemView;

   for(String item : strings) {
      TextView textView = TextView(context);
      textView.setText(item);
      parentLayout.addView(textView);
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to how the `ViewHolder` would look and the code within the `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder`. Could you please explain or give an example?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> // For each value, inflate a TextView layout...
> for (String value : values) {
>     // What goes here?
>     // How do I inflate the TextView layout (shown below) for each value and add it to the parent view?
> }
> ```

Since you're recycling views, you have to make sure that a few things are true:

- You have *enough* views to show all of your Strings
- You don't have *too many* views for the number of Strings in that cell

I am going to recommend that, when the LinearLayout has too many views, you simply hide them (rather than removing them). This will *increase* the memory consumption of your app, but will also *improve* the performance overall (since you will spend less time inflating views). You can revisit this later.

So, we need to make sure that we have enough views for your Strings. Let's do that first:

```
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) convertView;

while (linear.getChildCount() < values.size()) {
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_textview, linear);
}
```

Now let's fill up each TextView:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i) {
    String text = values.get(i);
    TextView textView = (TextView) linear.getChildAt(i);
    textView.setText(text);
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

And let's hide all the extra views:

```
for (int i = values.size(); i < linear.getChildCount(); ++i) {
    View v = linear.getChildAt(i);
    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

---

All the code together:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, parent, false);
    }

    LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) convertView;

    Map<Integer, List<String>> item = items.get(position);

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : item.entrySet()) {
        Integer key = entry.getKey();
        List<String> values = entry.getValue();

        for (String value : values) {
            while (linear.getChildCount() < values.size()) {
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_textview, linear);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i) {
                String text = values.get(i);
                TextView textView = (TextView) linear.getChildAt(i);
                textView.setText(text);
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            for (int i = values.size(); i < linear.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                View v = linear.getChildAt(i);
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Note that there's no need for a `ViewHolder` at all here, since you aren't using `findViewById()` anywhere. You can just delete all that code.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the answer! I'm having trouble understand how this code would fit within my adapter. You say that I don't need a `ViewHolder`, but I'm not sure where this code would go.

Comment: @user10817458 I've updated my answer with the code all put together inside `getView()`.

Comment: What would change if I were to use `ViewHolder` and `findViewById()`?

Comment: Unless your setup has changed dramatically, there's no reason to do so. There's nothing in your code that requires a `findViewById()` call; you just have a LinearLayout and can traverse the children in order. There would be no benefit to a `ViewHolder` in this case.